# Change state in parent component from child, then pass that state as property and change state in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component with two child components. A button click action should change state parent component and that should affect both of child components.

This is my parent component:

```
export default class SearchView extends React.Component {
  // attributes
  state = {
    loading: false
  }

  //
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  // get list of items
  getItems(){
    this.setState({loading:true})
    axios.get('/path_to_data').then( response => {
      this.setState({items:response.data, loading: false})
    }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchForm
          getItems={this.getItems.bind(this)}
          loading={this.state.loading}
        />
      { this.state.items ?  <ItemCards items={this.state.items} /> : "No data"}
      </div>
    )
  }//render

}//class
```

This is my component where click event happens:

```
export default class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  // attributes
  state = {
    loading: this.props.loading
  }

  // render
  render(){
    return (
      <Segment inverted color="yellow">
        <Grid columns="2">
          <Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column>
            <Button
              loading={this.state.loading}
              disabled={this.state.loading}
              color="black"
              onClick={this.props.getItems}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
      </Segment>
    )
  }//render

}//class SearchForm
```

and this is other child component:

```
export default class ItemCards extends React.Component {

  // constructor
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  // state
  state = {
    items: this.props.items
  }
  ...
```

The problem is that when a button is clicked I would expect that change in state object of `loading` attribute would be changed, and so would property passed into this same child component where event was triggered. And then I would expect this child component to detect that state of parent was changed and that property as well, and then it would change it's own state and UI would render `loading` attribute on element until response comes (when response comes, loading is removed).

Why doesn't this code work as expected? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the `<Button>` component shouldn't have any state, and just use props instead.

So try rewriting to:

```
<Button
   loading={this.props.loading} 
   disabled={this.props.loading}
   color="black"
   onClick={this.props.getHotels}>
```

The reason is that in react, you don't pass state from one component to another. State is something that is contained within an individual component. A good pattern is for the parent component to hold the state, and communicate with children via props.